# Software Center error in Zorin OS

Tags: zorin

**Hello** everyone
I install **Zorin OS** and when i open the **Software Center** after 1 or 2 minute or when i try to install any software i see that:
[image]
can some one tel me what is this problem and what I can to do for **fix** it?
And some thing I must says is this:
Zorin OS actually is the Ubuntu but with really little differents

Comment: says it can't connect to the server. Is that machine connected to the internet?

Comment: yes it's connected

Answer (score 1):

The message says it can't connect to the snapcraft server. Since you're certain the machine can access the internet, that server must be offline.

I checked that server, and it's reachable to me. Maybe you've not *fully* correctly set up your system? Is there some proxy to configure? A company firewall blocking these requests? Or do you have an authoritarian regime that blocks outgoing connections, or with whom snapcraft doesn't want anything to do:

> what I can to do for fix it?

If it is a network issue out of your control, nothing.

If it's an authorian regime, be careful please, but work towards democracy and cooperation. Do not endorse weapon programs and make it clear that if an idea that can't stand universal access to information, as misleading as that information might be, is probably an idea worth questioning.

If you can open http://api.snapcraft.io in your browser, but not your software center, then you'll need to go to your system settings and configure the proxy.

But honestly, this shouldn't make a difference to software installation. So, I'd just ignore it. You should always be able to use `apt install` from the console to install packages, and `apt search` to look for packages you want.

Comment: actully I use DNS proxy and it's work very well at other applications and I see this when I open http://api.snapcraft.io/:         https://i.imgur.com/uethyIC.png

Comment: yeah so that proxy is probably not configured in your system